# Replace column values to generate new data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The  code snippet below:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(
    {'type': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'A'],
     'value': [5, 6, 7, 7, 9, 1]}
)
```

Gives:

```
  type  value
0    A      5
1    B      6
2    A      7
3    C      7
4    C      9
5    A      1
```

Want this:-

```
pd.DataFrame(
    {'A': [5, 0, 7, 0, 0, 1],
     'B': [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     'C': [0, 0, 0, 7, 9, 0]}
)
   A  B  C
0  5  0  0
1  0  6  0
2  7  0  0
3  0  0  7
4  0  0  9
5  1  0  0
```

I did try using for loops but strive to be more efficient. Would be a great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) and multiply with the second column:

```
final_df=pd.get_dummies(df['type']).mul(df['value'],axis=0)
```

---

```
   A  B  C
0  5  0  0
1  0  6  0
2  7  0  0
3  0  0  7
4  0  0  9
5  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshape:

```
df = df.set_index('type', append=True)['value'].unstack(fill_value=0).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  5  0  0
1  0  6  0
2  7  0  0
3  0  0  7
4  0  0  9
5  1  0  0
```

Or numpy solution with multiple indicator DataFrame created by [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) with `numpy array`:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df['type']) * df['value'].values[:, None]
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  5  0  0
1  0  6  0
2  7  0  0
3  0  0  7
4  0  0  9
5  1  0  0
```

Comment: @anky_91 - yop, it is numpy :)